# Deserialize collection to empty list instead of `null` with System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization, json-deserialization

I'm using System.Text.Json.

I noticed that, when a collection property doesn't have a value, it's set to null.
This is a bit inconvenient, because it makes make check for null every time.

I'd like the serializer to initialize them to an empty list (List) or similar.

Comment: "because it makes make check for null every time" This is what you are supposed to do if you want to create robust code. Never assume that a nullable type variable can not be null. Nobody knows the way the class can be used

Comment: Create an instance of the List in the getter of the property when needed.

Answer (score 1):

In your class constructor, you can instanciate your collection.
Thus, it will never be `null`, except if `null` is explicitly provided in json

```
public class Sample
{
    public List<int> List { get; set; }

    public Sample()
    {
        this.List = new List<int>();
    }
}

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault
};
var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Sample>("{}", options);

Debug.Assert(result.List != null);
```

Comment: You still have a setter that can be used to set it to null. Safetywise you didn't get rid of checking for null.

Comment: @Ralf I agree with you. If `null` is explicitly stated in json string, the `List<int>` will be `null`

Comment: I didn't even meant the Json a simple `result.List = null;` works too.

Comment: @Ralf Yes, but that is not what's asking OP : `when a collection property doesn't have a value, it's set to null`

Comment: And he asked "because it makes make check for null every time."

Comment: @Ralf Agreed, null check will be always necessary :)